# Stretch height to container

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a background following [this example](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html), but I need to nest 2 containers.

My code look something like:

```
XHTML:
<body>
    <div id="background_shadow">
        <div id="container">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

css:
#background_shadow{ 
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */     
    height:100%;    
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */

    width: 876px;
    padding: 0px 72px;
    background: url("../images/background_shadow.png") repeat-y center;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg") repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the #container element isn't stretching with #background_shadow. Am I missing something? I would like to use nested container with 2 background image because one of them is transparent and if I use png instead of jpeg on the second image the filesize is too big (around 1Mo)

[Here is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A504N.png)

[And what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr1td.png)

I guess that if there arn't any solution I will need to use a big png.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to set min-height:100% to #containter, not height:100%.

Comment: No, I want the container stretching with #background_shadow's height. min-height don't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

For `height: 100%;` to work on an element, all parent elements need it, too (even `html` and `body`). So because of  `height: auto !important;`, it doesn't work anymore in the `#container` child.

You can either remove the `height: auto;` or add `#container { min-height: 100%; }`. I just tested it in Opera 11 and apparently `min-height` works just as fine. Don't know about IE, though.

Answer (score 0):

By the example you provided, your `#background_shadow` should have `position: relative`. That's going to allow it and it's children out of the restrictions of straight document flow.

Use Firebug to delete the footer from your example link - you'll see the div above it expand to fill the page even though it's content does not require the additional height.

Comment: This isn't working. What I would like is that the #content element from the example page stretch to fit the #container's height. But even with `height:100%;` it still act like `height: auto;` (stretch to inner content).